# iAd js developer library

Tags: javascript, ios, iad

I've been searching all over the internet and zig-zagging through the apple site, but have not been able to find the iad js developer library/api reference area/guide for iad producer.

does anyone know where to find it? because with out it, its near to impossible to properly develop/code for iad using javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

https://developer.apple.com/library/iad/navigation/

You need a developer account to access the site.

Comment: man i hate developing for apple products, all this nickel & diming they do. anyway thanks dude